# Making a calendar component scrollable on x and y axis

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm creating a calendar component with my own HTML/CSS.
It can have multiple categories across it's header horizontally (x-axis) and it will have up to 24 time slots down it's side vertically (y-axis).

The category headers must always be visible when scrolling vertically and the time slots must always be visible when scrolling horizontially.

How can I achieve this via css?

See screenshot for what I want (Image more tracks across header that results in content overflow).
[image]

Maybe take this as my sinple html structure:

```
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="calendarColumnHeaders"></div>
    <div class="calendarGrid">
        <div class="timeSlotsColumn"></div>
        <div class="tracksContainer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `<div class="tracksContainer"></div>` an extra class called `stick`

add this **Css:**

```
.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
```

And unfortunately, you do need some **Jquery**

**jQuery** – Calculates the position of the sticker div and makes its position fixed if the page has scrolled that far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $(".tracksContainer");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        s.html("Distance from top:" + pos.top + "<br />Scroll position: " + windowpos);
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks C Travel. This pointed me in the right direction. I added an scroll event handler to the tracksContainer div with x and y scrollbars, I then used the scrollTop() and scrollLeft() properties to adjust my track headers and times as the users scrolls the main container (tracksContainer).

Answer (score -1):

```
overflow-x: scroll; //horizontal
overflow-y: scroll; //vertical
```